# codeigniter get id sql injection

Tags: codeigniter

Codeigniter
Получаю GET вот так
$id = $this->input->get('id'); 
Но инъекция проходит, как обработать параметр GET?

Comment: id - целое? Тогда можно сделать ему `(int) $id` и все будет хорошо. Вообще, при построении запроса должны быть placeholder'ы, но с codeigniter не знаком, поэтому не могу сказать что там делать

Answer (score 1):

При использовании класса базы данных Codeigniter там происходит автоматическое экранирование, так что можете об этом не беспокоиться.
другими словами, работайте с базой данных через нативные функции Codeigniter'а, а не через непосредственно SQL

Answer (score 1):

Когда берешь параметры из массива `GET` или `POST`, пропускай их через фильтр XSS еще. Также в CI по умолчанию идет экранирование через Класс `Active Record`.

```
$this->input->get('id', TRUE); //фильтр XSS для get/post массива
```

И не пройдет инъекция.